# Ряд однородных или одно распространённое приложение?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, однородные-члены, приложение

Цитирую правило из справочника Розенталя:

> Если находящаяся в середине предложения группа однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточнения или **может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям**, то она с обеих сторон выделяется тире

В качестве примера, помимо прочих, приводится следующее предложение:

> Все присутствующие — делегаты и гости — внимательно слушали докладчика.

Однородные члены «делегаты и гости» выступают явно не уточнением, следовательно, автор приводит данное предложение в качестве аргументации выделения тире группы однородных членов, стоящих после обобщающего слова, которая **может быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям**. ПриложениЯМ — то есть здесь есть несколько приложений.

Но тут читаем следующее правило:

> 5. Если однородные члены предложения носят характер **приложения** или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире

И как пример в числе других дано такое предложение:

> Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы

Вопрос: не кажется ли вам, что ряд однородных членов и в первом и во втором предложении может быть приравнен к обособленному приложенИЮ, но никак не к приложениЯМ.

Comment: _Игорь Болотов: ... **но не как не** к приложениЯМ._ === Наверное, Вы хотели написать «**...но никак не...**»?

Comment: Так точно! Вы абсолютно правы!

Comment: Просто взгляд со стороны: думаю, раздавать минусы налево и направо (только потому, что Ваше _незыблемое_ мнение не совпадает с авторскими мнениями) — не есть хорошо, не есть здо́рово. _Вопрос: не кажется ли вам, что..._ Ответы: _нет, не кажется._ Для чего же тогда спрашивать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если находящаяся в середине предложения **группа однородных членов**,
> стоящих после обобщающего слова, имеет характер уточнения или **может
> быть приравнена к обособленным приложениям,** то она с обеих сторон
> выделяется тире.

Фраза построена грамматически верно.

```
                Вопрос: не кажется ли вам, что ряд однородных членов и в первом
               и во втором предложении может быть приравнен к обособленному 
               приложенИЮ, но никак не к приложениЯМ.
```

Нет, не кажется, ведь речь идёт о нескольких однородных приложениях

> Все присутствующие — делегаты и гости — внимательно слушали докладчика.

**Два однородных приложения, имеющих уточняющий характер.**

> Алый свет нежно заливал окрестности — ветряную мельницу, шиферные
> крыши машинно-тракторной станции, элеваторы.

**Четыре однородных приложения**, никак не одно приложение.
Так что всё верно.

Comment: «...Старики, отец и тесть, были еще живы». Данное предложение приводилось Розенталем как иллюстрация обособленного приложенИЯ, а не нескольких приложенИЙ. Почему?

Answer (score 1):

1. *Однородный ряд можно приравнять к обособленным **приложениям*** (мн. число).

Я думаю, что фраза корректна,  она означает, что однородный ряд можно отнести **к категории** обособленных приложений.

2. *Однородные члены предложения носят характер **приложения*** (ед. число).

Это тоже правильно. Характер **приложения** — это, другими словами, **определительный** характер, здесь возможно только единственное число.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110426/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon------).

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, суть вопроса не в правилах Розенталя, а в понимании выражений типа "А может быть приравнено к Б", "А носит характер Б".

Насколько я понимаю, автор вопроса считает, что если Б находится в множественном (единственном) числе, то это означает, что под А также понимается то же число. Это не обязательно так. Без примеров убеждать в подобном сложно, поэтому я приведу пару цитат из книг.

> Собственник, проживающий в своем доме, не может быть приравнен к
> нанимателям.
>
> По насыщенности витамином A абрикос может быть приравнен к шпинату,
> яичным желткам, маслу...

В первом предложении говорится, что "собственник" не может считаться "нанимателем" (принадлежать к группе нанимателей) в отношении самого себя, а во втором видно, что группа, к которой приравнивается объект, может обозначаться существительным в ед. или мн. числе.

С "характером" ситуация аналогичная, но на этот вопрос уже ответили.